# No compatible version found: grunt-contrib-concat@'node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat'

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I recently received website that consists of an index.html, sass files, javascript files and a few configuration files.  I tried to run the command `npm install` in the main project directory and I got the following error.

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: grunt-contrib-concat@'node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.2.0","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","1.0.0","1.0.1","0.1.2-rc5","0.1.2-rc6"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/project.com/public_html_staging
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/project.com/public_html_staging/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

This is what my `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "glob": "~4.3.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-concat-css": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I'm really new to the `npm` command and any related subject matter.  How do I begin to troubleshoot this error?  Or does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that I was using NodeJS version 0.1 while the project was originally built on a server that had NodeJS v5.  Hence the npm didn't have all the right grunt dependencies.

I did the following as root user on my affected server

```
apt-get purge nodejs
apt-get purge npm
apt-get autoremove // remove any orphan dependences
```

Once I got rid of everything, I install version 6 of NodeJS as per the nodejs website with these commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The NodeJS already came with it's own npm, so I didn't need to do anything else.

Then when I ran `npm install`, it properly downloaded all the necessary modules to run my project.